# What shall I use to start before a subsentence, which or with?

Tags: grammar

> Jane is the best student with her math score of 100.

Or

> Jane is the best student, which her math score is 100.

Which one is the more appropriate expression?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the two, your first sentence is better. The preposition "with" implying possession of something.

> **with - preposition:** having or possessing (something).
>
> "a flower-sprigged blouse with a white collar."

That said, I would consider dropping the pronoun 'her' from your sentence and replacing it with the determiner 'a' and writing it as:

> "Jane is the best student with a math score of 100."

Finally, and this is more about style, I think the following reads the best and maintains intent and meaning. Jane is the object of the sentence and therefore reads better when placed at the end. The subject (her 100 math score) is the subject and therefore should be set at the beginning.

> "With a math score of 100 Jane is the best student."

https://www.tesol-direct.com/tesol-resources/english-grammar-guide/subjects-and-objects/

Answer (score 1):

The Original Poster could  use a *with*-preposition phrase here:

> Jane is the best student with her math score of 100.

Alternatively, they could use a relative clause. However, the relative clause needs to modify a noun phrase in the matrix clause and also needs to be a genitive NP Determiner within the relative clause. The ideal *wh-* word here would be *whose*. This would need to replace the relativised element *her* within the relative clause, and would need to occur after *Jane*, because *Jane* is what we are providing more information about:

> Jane, whose maths score is 100, is the best student.